# How to efficiently multiply two matrix row by column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I use the following toy example to show my question:

```
A = np.ones((3,2))
B = np.ones((2,3))
res = np.zeros(3,)

for i in range(0,3):
    res[i] = A[i,:].dot(B[:,i])
print res
```

The printed result is

```
[ 2.  2.  2.]
```

That is, give matrix `A` and `B`, what I hope to do is to multiply 1st row of `A` with 1st column of `B`, then 2nd, 3rd, ...
In other words, suppose the two matrix:

```
A                                    B
[ a11, a12                      [ b11, b12
  a21, a22 ]                      b21, b22 ]
```

What I want is

```
[ a11 * b11 + a12 * b21, a21 * b12 + a22 * b22 ]
```

I know my implementation is quite slow. Is there any method to implement this quickly?
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum("ij,ji->i" , A, B)
# array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Another example:

```
A = np.array([[1,3],[4,5]])
B = np.array([[3,2],[1,1]])

A
#array([[1, 3],
#       [4, 5]])

B
#array([[3, 2],
#       [1, 1]])

np.einsum("ij,ji->i" , A, B)
# array([ 6, 13])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `B.T` to transpose `B` and multiply `A` and `B` element-wise.

```
C = A*B.T
C = np.sum(C, axis=1)
```